# Nested routes on static route prefix for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

New to Ruby on Rails and can't get my routes to work how I want them to. Basically, I have two api endpoints: One is for one of the platform services I offer, and the second is for a child platform I'd like to offer next.The resulting URL schemes I want are

...com/api/ # First API platform

...com/stubs/api # Second API platform

The second API platform has resources, but there are no specific resources for "subs" or "api". I am just using that as delineation between the products.

Here is what my `routes.rb` looks like:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :auth

  match :api, to: 'api#index', via: :all

  match :stubs, to: 'stubs#index', via: :get 

  match 'stubs/api', to: 'stubs/api#index', via: :get
  scope  'stubs/api' do
    resources :enpoints
  end

end
```

and then my Controllers...

```
# controllers/stubs/api/endpoints_controller.rb
class Stubs::Api::EndpointsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render :json => {}
    end
end
```

When I try to render `/stubs/api/endpionts` I get the error:

> No route matches [GET] "/stubs/api/endpoints"

My apologies in advance if this is a bad noob problem, bu the articles I found didn't seem to resolve the issue.... Likely because I am thinking of it wrong from the ground up? In any case, thanks for your help in advance!

And even more confusing my routes show the endpoint is there as expected:[image]

**UPDATE**

Adding my folder structure too in case that helps. 
[image]

How is this a possible result page????
[image]

Comment: why are you render `/stubs/api/endpionts`

Comment: use the following instead, `namespace :stubs do namespace :api do resources :endpoints end end`

Comment: thanks @Md.FarhanMemon. I used namespace instead as Puneet suggested below as well, but still not working. I have added more screenshots as well in the post above....

Comment: I should also note, "endpoints" is confusing but it is a name of an endpoint of the api.... /api/endpoints/ is interchangeable with /api/users/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below routes in route.rb file:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :stubs do #use namespace instead of scope
    namespace :api do
      resources :enpoints
    end
  end

  resources :auth

  match :api, to: 'api#index', via: :all

  match :stubs, to: 'stubs#index', via: :get 

  match 'stubs/api', to: 'stubs/api#index', via: :get


end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @puneet18, but I still get the `No route matches [GET] "/stubs/api/endpoints"` error when I go to `/stubs/api/endpoints`. It is so weird that it says the endpoint isn't there in the error, and then lists the exact endpoint in the `Routes` list output....

Comment: @Sean check my updated answer and change your routes.rb file

Comment: Nope, no go. I added a screen shot of the resulting page once I made the routes they way you posted.